# Bootstrap column full content background-color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

This is what I want to do : 
[image]

And this is what I have : 
[image]

And this is my code :

Html

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-md-6">col-md-6 ...</div>
  <div class="col-md-2">col-md-2</div>
</div>
```

Css

```
.col-md-4,.col-md-2 {
background-color: #e3e3e3;
}

.col-md-6 {
background-color: #f5f3f3;
}
```

I checked other questions on the subject but I'm not satisfied with the answers... can someone help me to improve my code ? thank you !

Comment: How about you put that coulums to one div with row class?

Comment: thanks wijaya, i was already doing this but I forgot to add it to my question's code

Comment: What about adding the background-color to the `.row` instead? http://jsbin.com/korizi/1/edit?css,output

Comment: If you want to fill a column background with some colour for entire height of the row look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695784/how-can-i-make-bootstrap-columns-all-the-same-height and mark this one as duplicate

Answer (score 8):

Look here in **[JSFiddle...](http://jsfiddle.net/xd7y62tm/)**
I hope you are looking for this output. If yes then try the following code:

[image: Ouput of the JSFiddle code]

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 row-height">
        <span>col-md-4</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 row-height">
        col-md-6
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 row-height">
        col-md-2
    </div>
</div>
```

**And CSS:**

```
.row {
    padding: 100px;
}

.row-height {
    height: 70px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 25px;
}

.col-md-4,.col-md-2 {
    background-color: #e3e3e3;
}

.col-md-6 {
    background-color: #f5f3f3;
}

.col-md-4 {
    border-radius: 15px 0 0 15px;
}

.col-md-2 {
    border-radius: 0 15px 15px 0;
}
```

You can modify the CSS the way you want and sizes in the styles according to the content.

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 2):

You could color the entire `.row` and then the middle column separately..

```
.row {
    background-color: #e3e3e3;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

.col-md-6 {
    background-color: #f5f3f3;
}
```

http://codeply.com/go/FXSkrecwwI

Comment: It doesn't work if there is larger content in left column.

Answer (score 1):

Try this CSS:

```css
.row {
  display: table; 
  width: 100%; 
}

.col {
  display: table-cell;
}

.col-md-4,
.col-md-2 {
  background-color: #e3e3e3;
}

.col-md-6 {
  background-color: #f5f3f3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a custom class say `myfix` to the column div elements and set `height:100%;`.